# New TAG: Office-connect

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Office-Connect is a needed tag.

this leads me to a question : do we need a TAG for every external APP by salesforce? (some are already existing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag created - Is this that everyone can create tag while in Beta?